# How to use npm link to start a package with an express server?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-scripts

I am currently developing an NPM package which launches an express server for hosting images. This exists in a directory within a Laravel project.

Currently this is still in development and I want to develop this into a publishable module, so I added a .gitignore for this package in my Laravel project.

Within my NPM package I ran `npm link` and in my Laravel project I ran `npm link imageserver`, **imageserver** being the name of my package. This makes sure I can develop my package without constantly having to publish and pull in new changes with NPM.

I can require the package inside my JavaScript with a `require()` statement now, but I simply want to run the express server that is this package through npm scripts.

In the **imageserver** package I have set up a `package.json` containing this:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "nodemon app.js"
}
```

How can I call the `npm run start` script on a package that I have linked?

In my Laravel project I would simply like to start my linked server package like so:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "imageserver"
}
```

But in this case I am getting:

> imageserver: not found

Normally you can run packages fine from the NPM scripts if they are installed in your `node_modules` directory. Is this not the case for linked packages?

**Edit**

I have added a `bin` property to my `package.json` file to make it executable and add it to my global path. At least this way I can call `imageserver` from my NPM scripts and it works. Now I am getting permission errors though:

```
//: Permission denied
/home/workstation/.nvm/versions/node/v10.1.0/bin/imageserver: 2: /home/workstation/.nvm/versions/node/v10.1.0/bin/imageserver: global.__base: not found
/home/workstation/.nvm/versions/node/v10.1.0/bin/imageserver: 4: /home/workstation/.nvm/versions/node/v10.1.0/bin/imageserver: //: Permission denied
/home/workstation/.nvm/versions/node/v10.1.0/bin/imageserver: 5: /home/workstation/.nvm/versions/node/v10.1.0/bin/imageserver: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made my main JavaScript file in my `imageserver` package executable and added a shebang:

In my directory.

```
chmod +x filename.sh
```

In my file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

My `package.json` for the `imageserver` package has this now:

```
"bin": "app.js",
```

When I ran `npm link` it added `imageserver` as an executable to my path and I can execute it as a third party package from `scripts` section of a project that needs it.

It works now, it currently is not being controlled by nodemon anymore, I just need to figure out how to get that working again.